# ListView doesn't update while typing on SearchView until I hide the keyboard

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin, searchview

I'm creating an Android app that connects to Azure Search Service. I added a SearchView and a ListView. The idea is that as I type on the SearchView, I get live results from Azure Search and I display them on the ListView as is common functionality.

The problem I have is that the ListView doesn't get updated while the Android keyboard is displayed. So initially the ListView is empty, I type a couple of letters in the SearchView, nothing appears on the ListView, but if I tap the Android back button (at this point a down button) to hide the Android keyboard then the ListView is populated and the search results appear.

If I type in 3, 4 or more letters I see the right results but only when I hide the keyboard.

This is basically my code:

```
private SearchView searchView;
private ListView listView;
private ArrayAdapter<string> adapter;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

    searchView = FindViewById<SearchView>(Resource.Id.searchBox);
    listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.searchResult);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1);
    listView.Adapter = adapter;

    searchView.QueryTextChange += SearchView_QueryTextChange;
}

private void SearchView_QueryTextChange(object sender, SearchView.QueryTextChangeEventArgs e)
{
    adapter.Clear();
    if (e.NewText.Length > 1)
    {
        searchTerm(e.NewText);
    }
}

private async void searchTerm(string newText)
{
    var client = new RestClient("mysearchengine.search.windows.net");
    var request = new RestRequest("indexes/myitems/docs/search", Method.POST);

    request.AddParameter("api-version", "2017-11-11", ParameterType.QueryString);
    request.AddHeader("api-key", "MYKEY");
    request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    request.AddBody(new { search = newText + "*", select = "id, title" });

    try {
        await Task.Run(() => {
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        if (response.StatusDescription == "OK")
        {
            string values = response.Content;
            List<MyPost> myPosts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyPost>>(values);
            List<string> items = new List<string>();
            for(int i=0;i<myPosts.Count;i++)
            {
                items.Add(myPosts[i].Title + " (" + myPosts[i].ID + ")");
            }
            adapter.AddAll(items);
            adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
    catch(Exception e) { }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should use a query listener [SearchView.OnQueryTextListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener)